# How can I create a form with a web action in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, forms

How can I create a form and then set an action, such as:

```
<form name='client_login_form_' action='http://www.dhsb.org/index.phtml?d=187209&destination_page=187224' method=post>
```

I need to do this with two UITextFields.

Once a button is pressed, the data needs to be taken from the two UITextFields then put into an action, like the HTML above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to submit a web form from an iOS app, take a look at `ASIHTTPRequest`.  From their docs:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Fill in the values from your `UITextField`s.  And implement the delegate methods if you want to receive back a response.

Comment: I've tried using ASIHTTPRequest in the past, but I get hundreds of errors as I'm using the latest version of XCode and they don't seem to like each other - is there another way of doing the same thing? :(

Comment: I'm using ASIHTTPRequest in a couple of projects with Xcode 4.2, with no errors.  You can do the same using NSURLConnection, with only a little more effort - the same basic approach applies.

Comment: Please can you provide a small example for NSURLConnection please? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)*.  You'll need to create an `NSURL`, then an `NSURLRequest`, and then pass that to an `NSURLConnection`.  You'll probably want to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to encode your `UITextField` values before putting them in the URL (or `NSURLRequest.HTTPBody`).